# Java convert hex string to java: char[] (C) to byte[] (JAVA)

Tags: java, c

How to convert hex string in java that keep the same values.

In C i have:

```
char tab[24] = { 0x02, 0x04, 0xF3, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0x06, 0x00, 0xF7, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0xFD, 0xFD, 0x00, 0x03, 0x0A, 0xFD, 0x02, 0xFD, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0x01, 0xFD };
```

And i copy to java like a string;

```
String hexString = "0x02, 0x04, 0xF3, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0x06, 0x00, 0xF7, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0xFD, 0xFD, 0x00, 0x03, 0x0A, 0xFD, 0x02, 0xFD, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0x01, 0xFD";
```

Now i want to convert in byte[], i find some ways how to do it but it looks like i do not convert in right format.

**SOLVED**

```
String[] split = hexString.split(", ");       
byte[] arr = new byte[split.length];
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = (byte)(short)Short.decode(split[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you actually want to convert the given string to a `byte[]` (though this seems like a strange requirement)...

```
String hexString = "0x02, 0x04, 0xF3, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0x06, 0x00, 0xF7, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0xFD, 0xFD, 0x00, 0x03, 0x0A, 0xFD, 0x02, 0xFD, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0x01, 0xFD";
String[] split = hexString.split(", ");
byte[] arr = new byte[split.length];
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
{
   arr[i] = (byte)Short.parseShort(split[i].substring(2), 16);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

We need to use `parseShort` instead of `parseByte` because trying to parse something like `0xF3` with `parseByte` causes `NumberFormatException: Value out of range`.

Prints:

```
[2, 4, -13, -4, -1, 6, 0, -9, 0, 0, 9, -3, -3, 0, 3, 10, -3, 2, -3, 8, 8, 0, 1, -3]
```

Comment: Now i have something similar. Insted of short integer. So which one is better?

Comment: Instead of using `parseShort`, you could also say `arr[i] = (byte)(short)Short.decode(split[i]);` which will automatically recognize the "0x" at the front of the string if it's there.  The extra cast is needed to unbox the Short.

Answer (score 2):

What you have in C would be this in Java:

```
byte[] tab = { 0x02, 0x04, (byte) 0xF3, (byte) 0xFC, (byte) 0xFF, 0x06, 
               0x00, (byte) 0xF7, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, (byte) 0xFD, (byte) 0xFD, 
               0x00, 0x03, 0x0A, (byte) 0xFD, 0x02, (byte) 0xFD, 0x08, 
               0x08, 0x00, 0x01, (byte) 0xFD };
```

Note that instead of `char` you use `byte`, and that values that are outside of the allowed range for `byte` such as 0xFD need an explicit cast. And you don't include the array length in the declaration.

---

**Update:** To not add casts manually you can declare the data of a wider type (like int or short) and then loop over it:

```
int[] temp = { ... };
byte[] tab = new byte[temp.length];
for (int i = 0; i<temp.length; i++) tab[i]=(byte)temp[i];
```

A better solution would be loading the data from an external file though. Big array literals are not encoded into class files in a compact way like C compilers encode big array literals.

Comment: I already see this way but in real i have char array 10504 long so i don't want to write cast notation. Thanks anyway

Comment: @rikkima You can use the above but instead a `short[]` (thus no casting needed) and have a simple for-loop run through and cast each one to `byte` and put it in the `byte[]`, i.e. `for (int i=0; i<shortArr.length; i++) byteArr[i] = (byte)shortArr[i];`

Answer (score 0):

@Joni has the right answer. But if you want to do this on runtime you  can do something like:

```
    String hex = "0xFFFFFFFF";
    long longRep = Long.decode(hex);
    byte[] byteRep = String.valueOf(intrRep).getBytes("UTF-8");

    //to verify
    System.out.println(Long.toHexString(Long.valueOf(new String(byteRep,"UTF-8"))));
```